# Hide Empty Rows in Cardboard

Tags: rally

Is it possible to hide rows without cards within the rallycardboard?  I did not see any row config, and I cannot find an easy way to loop through the rows and find which ones are empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are basing your rows on a field with a constrained set of values (ScheduleState, a custom dropdown field, etc) the board will render a row for each value, whether there are cards or not.  This sounds like what you're running into.  It would probably be a nice addition to the component to be able to pass in a config to show empty rows or not.

In the meantime, you should be able to work around it by adding a load listener to the board, looping over the rows and then just collapsing them if they are empty.

```
this.add({
    xtype: 'rallycardboard',
    rowConfig: {
        //your rowConfig
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function(board) {
            var rows = board.getRows();
            _.each(rows, function(row) {
                var cardsInRow = board.getCardsInRow(row);
                var cardCount = _.flatten(_.values(cardsInRow)).length;
                if(cardCount === 0) {
                    row.collapse();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Kyle.  getCardsInRow is exactly what I was looking for.  The row.collapse() works, but is there any function recommended to remove these rows?  I believe row.destroy() would work, but I am not sure what negative impact this would have.  Also, as a side note...do you know a way to update the text within the row?  I am thinking about adding the count of cards per row to the row text would be nice.

Comment: You should be able to call board.removeRow(row); to fully remove the row.  That should be fully supported. I forgot about that method.

Comment: I don't see a fully supported way to customize the header text.  That would be another good addition to the component.  The easiest way now would probably be to pass in an implementation of _getTitle in the rowConfig's headerConfig:

rowConfig: {
    headerConfig: {
        _getTitle: function() { return this.getValue() + 'myCustomTitle';} 
    }
}

Comment: Do you recommend a best practice for passing the card count into a variable for replacing the 'myCustomTitle?  I am able to get the count on the row object (as you reference above), but cannot access from the rowConfig: headerConfig.

Comment: That's a good question.  You'll probably have to do a global lookup of the board component using Ext.ComponentQuery.query('rallycardboard')[0] and then go from there.  As you've found there are some opportunities for improvement with this component, but at least you can work around most of it for now...